# JQuery Multiple Predict Box Off Options With Delete Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Like the Stackoverflow tagging section to tag multiple categories for answers to be categorized correctly, I would like to use the JQuery multiple predictive or similar on my advanced search and upon typing a comma, they will become boxed off like they do on Stackoverflow.

[image: Screenshot of Stackoverflow's tagging]

Does anyone know either how to modify the JQuery multiple predict or know of a plugin which bests describe my description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use tag-it available on Github [here](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)

Check out here for a [demo](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! ...Ironic about the same name too... Destiny? hehe!